# Как я могу связать столбцы без свойства уникальности

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Отношение между IdProd из Distribution и ключевым в этом отношении IdProd из Sales
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так она должна будет выглядеть полностью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните что это за таблицы и как они педставлены в реальной жизни. По текущей картинке не ясно зачем вообще надо связывать idProd из distribution именно с таблицей Sales

Comment: Это не полная база таблиц, но мне нужно связать продажу с торговой точкой

Comment: Торговая точка, это что, в какой оно таблице ? И почему вы хотите это делать по idProd, который похож на id товара ?

Comment: Чтобы найти соотношение объема продаж к накладным расходам (суммарная заработная плата продавцов + платежи за аренду, коммунальные услуги) за указанный период. Продажи привязаны к торговой точке

Comment: но вообще, если не смотреть на эту схему, то в жизни конкретная продажа происходит в одной конкретной торговой точке. А в таком случае в таблице продаж должен быть id торговой точки, в которой она произошла

Comment: Я понял. Тогда через IdPurch всьо получится.

Comment: Ну если я правильно понял названия таблиц, то я имел ввиду, что в Sales надо добавить idOutlet

Comment: @Mike Я добавил то, как она должна будет выглядеть

Comment: Ну да, так хорошо. Если продавцы не могут совмещать работу в нескольких торговых точках

Comment: И что такое "распределение" не ясно. и как оно с продажами связано

Comment: @Mike Т.е. должен буду заполнять IdOutlet в таблице Sales по значению IdSeller?

Comment: ну сейчас это явно не требуется, потому как у вас есть связь через продавца. Тут уже вопрос постановки, допустима ли работа продавца одновременно в нескольких точках продажи или нет. Если допустима, то у вас у продавца не будет уже одного idOutlet, а будет выбор и надо будет как то в интерфейсе пользователя это обыгрывать, определять из какой торговой точки работал продавец

Comment: @Mike А если привязка только к одной точке?

Comment: ну тогда у вас уже все верно. Вы всегда можете получить торговую точку продажи через продавца